# Does Mongoid have Map/Reduce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am using Ruby code to calculate sum from the array returned by Mongoid.

But maybe using Map/Reduce can be faster, except I don't see any docs for Map Reduce on mongoid.org and Google for

```
map reduce site:mongoid.org
```

doesn't give any result either.  (or using `MapReduce` or `Map/Reduce`)

There are docs on MongoDB's site

```
map reduce site:mongodb.org
```

but need to use Map Reduce with  Mongoid as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use map reduce with Mongoid just as you could through the Ruby driver directly:

```
# Post is a Mongoid model...
Post.collection.map_reduce(map_function, reduce_function, options)
```

For some examples of doing map reduce in the Ruby driver, see [this blog post](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/12/mongodb-map-reduce-basics/) by Kyle Banker (maintainer of the Ruby MongoDB driver).

Comment: hm, so this is to go a lower level route by using the Ruby driver for MongoDB... not by using Mongoid per se?  Maybe if Mongoid has it directly it can be better... (does having Mongoid imply you also have the Ruby driver or it has to be separate?)  As of right now, if I use `Analytics.collection` it returns a `Mongoid::Collection` object. `Analytic.collection.methods.grep /map/`
 => `["mapreduce", "map_reduce"]`, so map_reduce is defined.

Comment: Mongoid runs on top of the Ruby driver, and using the method above just passes the functions through to the Ruby driver.

Comment: so maybe Mongoid can put that into their formal docs huh?  that Mongoid supports Map/Reduce by using the Ruby driver.